# Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.4

Tags: android, external, library-project

I changed the gradle version from 2.4 to 2.1 but it not worked for me 
I changed version in ...\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties file
original contenet of file is:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

And updated content are:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

But issue is not resolved

Comment: why you are going to down gradle version

Comment: i used the same I.E. 2.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the distributionUrl to;

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

This sets the gradle version to 2.10, which, as the error says, is required...

Comment: my url is same as you given